# How to detect if a HWND belong to my application?

Tags: c++, winapi

My application creates multiple windows and I want to enforce a Z order in-between these windows, i.e, if two windows happen to overlap, a window with a higher priority should be painted over the window with lower priority.

I am getting the handles of different (invisible/visible) windows wrt to a window using the [GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515(v=vs.85).aspx) function. I want to know if a particular window returned by this function is created by my application. Any ideas on how can I get that information?

Comment: You know what the window handles are because they are in your application. Why do you need to grab the entire toplevel window hierarchy? And even then, you can still just compare the window handle you get against your own window handles, because you know them. Also owned windows always appear above owner windows; this is probably the thing you want to do instead of your current approach.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318087(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @andlabs I am also trying to enforce my windows to be top of other windows not owned by my application (i know that's not a good practice. I am just trying out a few things right now.)

Comment: Yeah, set the owner and that's it.

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook you should have said that in your original question... (You only said you were interested in enforcing a Z-order across the windows in your application only, not across the entire system.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [[MS.Docs]: GetWindowThreadProcessId function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid).

In order to check the current process id, use [[MS.Docs]: GetCurrentProcessId function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocessid).

If your app is more complex and spawns multiple processes that create windows, you'll  have to construct the process tree using [[MS.Docs]: Tool Help Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/ToolHelp/tool-help-functions) ((*CreateToolhelp32Snapshot*, *Process32First*, *Process32Next*) + *CloseHandle*).